# Web Api advise on redirecting calls, load balancing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, load-balancing

I have my `Web Api application` distributed on three servers using `Load Balancer` with `Round Robin` rule. Every server can proceed `only one request` for specified RestApi endpoint http://MyServer/api/LongRunningProcees
If second request is posted to the same Rest API endpoint when first one is not finished a server return 503 Service unavailable.

I am new to load balancing and I don't find any solution how to redirect the request to another server until it will be accepted. Is this Load Balancer responsibility?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that maximally only 3 request can be processed simultaneously? What do you want to do if there is a new request and all servers are busy?

Comment: This is just example, we are using the scale up option to add more cloud servers when needed. The actual problem is that using Round Robin a Load Balancer can hit the same server which is still proceeding the RestApi End Point though other servers could be available for the same RestApi End Point.

Comment: What Load Balancer do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *Round Robin* algorithm then you have to accept that some servers will be busy while others will be waiting for requests. This algorithm simply works in this way.

However, there are also other algorithms. For example *Least response time* which selects servers based on the response time from the servers. The details depends on the used Load Balancer.

Besides, it seems to me that a server should not return 503 error if it is busy. Instead a request should be put into some kind of queue and wait until a server is available. If requests are processed in a similar time and an suitable balancing algorithm is used then all server should have the similar number of requests in their queues.